# Reading PDF file using Acrobat SDK with C#.net

Tags: c#, pdf, acrobat-sdk

How to read the pdf file using Acrobat SDK? I don't want any third party tool/dll like iText etc. I need to read via Acrobat SDK. I just gone thr the adobe site, documents bit complex and dig little.. Any one expert in Adobe SDK help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Acrobat SDK comes with a COM-based automation interface. [Read more.](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/10/Acrobat10_HTMLHelp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.2.html)

See [SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469802/net2-0-c-sharp-interop-how-to-call-com-code-from-c) about calling COM from C#.

Comment: The SDK link is now broken.

Comment: The error page says 'Site Area Temporarily Unavailable'. This is the same URL that Adobe points to from their own offline docs (PDF) so for now I assume it is really temporarily. Will check again later.

Comment: It seems broken again.

Answer (score -1):

The developer centre at Adobe is helpful.

Go to: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html

Also have look at the link below

Acrobat XI Tips & Tricks

http://tv.adobe.com/show/acrobat-xi-tips-tricks/