# C# COM Class - DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, com, vbscript

I have declared a COM visible class in C#. The code is as follows:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class AComVisibleClass : TheParentClass
{
    public bool SomeFunc(string id)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This class is instantiated by a factory class, also COM accessible.

But if I try to access in a VB script file, a `DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME` exception is thrown.

This is a new class on a pre-existent library we have here at work. All other classes are accessible through COM. The whole library is compiled into a single assembly file. I have registered the new assembly using `regasm`, but I still get this exception.

I've tried to debug the COM call using VS2008. The factory class seems to be able to instantiate the `AComVisibleClass`. The aforementioned exception is thrown only when the factory tries to execute `SomeFunc`.

I know this may sound a little(?) bit vague, but I cannot expose the real code here. If someone need more information, please ask me.

Comment: Can you add your VBScript code (just enough to see how the call looks like)?

Comment: The problem is in the VBScript code.  You didn't post that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can think of three possible reasons for this problem:

**Reason 1: Wrong name used in CreateObject:**

I suppose that your VBScript code calls
 something like
 this:

```
 Set obj = CreateObject("MyLibrary.AComVisibleClass")
```

If this is correct, then please open the registry editor and check whether the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key contains a subkey called `MyLibrary.AComVisibleClass`.
If it does not, then your library name possibly is different than you expected. Search the registry for `AComVisibleClass` to find the correct library name.

**Reason 2: 64-bit issues:**

If the problem happens on a 64-bit operating system, the reason could be that your VBScript runs as a 32-bit process and the C# COM DLL is 64-bit or vice versa.

**Reason 3: Wrong function name:**

You might be using the wrong function name in the script, e.g. `obj.SomeFnc(1)` instead of `obj.SomeFunc(1)`, or the function name you have chosen is a reserved keyword in VBScript or it contains unusual characters.

Comment: I was able to find out what was happening. All I can say is that my problem was a little more complex that I described here... BUT this is the most helpful answer, and so will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to support `IDispatch`.

Check out [Does C# .NET support IDispatch late binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403218/does-c-net-support-idispatch-late-binding)

*edit*

This answer is likely wrong, and I may yet wind up deleting it. For now, it seems to add value, so I'll let it stay.

Comment: .NET exposes dual interfaces (i.e. including IDispatch) by default for ComVisible stuff, so that shouldn't be the issue here.

Comment: @Pavel, you're right. It looks like `IDispatch` is implemented but the caller is not passing in the correct name. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vsconstants.disp_e_unknownname(VS.80).aspx) Could it be case sensitivity?