# How can I override Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction to accept int using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm trying to convert a password protected ms access database to `ACCDE` I tried a lot of things like the following :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application AccApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();
string MyFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Baseet.accdb";
string MyCompiledFile = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Baseet.accde";

AccApp.Visible = true;
AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(MyFile, false, "017014A");
AccApp.RunCommand(AcCommand.acCmdAppMaximize);

AccApp.SysCmd (603 , MyFile , MyCompiledFile);
```

But I got this compiler error on 603 :

> Cannot convert from int to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction

I looked at the documentation for `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acsyscmdaction) But I couldn't find that command although it exists in VBA , It turned out to be undocumented command.

How can I fix it , Any help appreciated .

Comment: I don't think you can use undocumented functions/enums through the primary interop assemblies. I recommend using unbound COM instead.

Comment: @ErikA Thanks for replying , I don't know about that could you make a demo code ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I mean late-bound COM. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/403218/7296893, example is Excel but principles should translate. Look for the answer with dynamic, as that's much easier than the older accepted answer.